# Unity session closes when press Alt-Tab, Super, Super-F, Super-A

Tags: 14.04, unity

Something went wrong and Unity get broken. Now I can't switch windows by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and can't use unity's finders, but can use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

How can I fix that?

P.S.

I've already tried:

```
unity --replace
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity
```

Answer (score 0):

While switching off compiz plugins I realized that actually crashes compiz, not unitty itself. Then I started in a terminal a new compiz instance: `compiz --replace` which somehow prevented session termination when compiz crashed.

In the compiz log which was outputted to the terminal I've seen the error of absent file /usr/share/unity/icons/dash_bottom_right_corner.png

As soon as I copied to it dash_bottom_left_corner.png and restarted compiz it had stopped crashing.

I guess I lost that file when several times rebooted hardly my notebook and fsck-ed it.